# Logcat error: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android

When I run my app, I get the logcat error as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.enxin.crystallise, PID: 14868
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.enxin.crystallise/com.example.enxin.crystallise.Help}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at com.example.enxin.crystallise.Help.onCreate(Help.java:11)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #32: Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.enxin.crystallise.HelpFragment
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2260)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
   at com.example.enxin.crystallise.Help.onCreate(Help.java:11) 
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Here's the code where my error lies in:

```
public class Help extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    }
}
```

activity_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.enxin.crystallise.Help">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/title_help"
        android:id="@+id/title_help"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/subtitle_help"
        android:id="@+id/subtitle_help"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_help"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.enxin.crystallise.HelpFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subtitle_help"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_help" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_helo.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/help1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/help1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/help2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/help2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/help1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/help3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_below="@+id/help2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

HelpFragment.java

```
package com.example.enxin.crystallise;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.enxin.crystallise.R;

public class HelpFragment extends Fragment {


public HelpFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);
}

}
```

When I request to see the error, the line setContentView is highlighted. I'm new to Android Studio so please help!

Comment: Problem in your layout, pls post your activity_help.xml too

Comment: Can you please share your Fragment class too?

Comment: I was expecting HelpFragment.java instead of xml. Please share your HelpFragment.java too.

Comment: Is this a typo?  You're saying that the xml is called: `fragment_helo.xml` and you're inflating `fragment_help.xml`

Comment: oops it was a typo @Vucko

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in your Java class, it's located in the XML file where you have declared the layout for the View.
It must have problem with id or tag, be sure to check all the attributes are as required per the standards.
And also, post the code of that file.(XML file containing the fragment)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in `fragment_help.xml`, You forgot to close `RelativeLayout` tag.

Just put `</RelativeLayout>` end of the layout file.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: i added it in but still cant @Neo but thanks anyway i really appreciate it :)